# Geometry of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

Let $K$ be a number field, $\rho_1,\dots,\rho_{r}$ its real embeddings, and $\sigma_1,\bar{\sigma_1},\dots,\sigma_{s},\bar{\sigma_{s}}$ its complex embeddings. There's a map
\begin{align*}
K &\rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{r}\mathbb{R}\times\prod_{i=1}^{s}\mathbb{C}\\
x  &\mapsto (\rho_i(x))_{i=1}^r\times(\sigma_i(x))_{i=1}^s
\end{align*}
If we further identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ by sending $z$ to $(\text{Re}(z),\text{Im}(z))$, then we get a map $K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{r+2s}$. The geometry of numbers says the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is sent to a complete lattice in this vector space (see for example Neukirch chapter 1 proposition 5.2).

**Question :** Can we always choose a set of representatives of $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{r+2s}$ such that they all live in some cone ? Or do we have a natural choice of a set of representatives of $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ which admits some simple description ?

I suppose this has been already answered in the literature but don't know where to find it. Any hint or reference would be highly appreciated.

---

Here are some examples

1. $K=\mathbb{Q}$ : Then we may choose $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ to be $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$. So our cone is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.
2. $K=\mathbb{Q}[i]$ : Then we may choose $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ to be $\{a+bi\mid a\geq 1, b\geq 0\}$. So our cone is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.
3. $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ : I don't know how to describe $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ even in this simple case.

Comment: In the case of $K=\Bbb Q[\sqrt2\,]$, do you know the nature of $\mathcal O_K^\times$ ?

Comment: @Lubin Yes, $\mathcal{O}_K^\times=\pm (1-\sqrt{2})^n$ in this case. In general Dirichlet's unit theorem says that $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is of rank $r+s-1$, so at first I (wrongly) thought that $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ should be  $s+1$-dimensional in some sense, then I guessed that one could find $x_1,\dots,x_n\in K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ s.t. $(\mathcal{O}_K\setminus\{0\})/\mathcal{O}_K^\times=\cup x_i\mathbb{Z}$ (up to some problem with torsion), but this is not correct of course..